# How to query mongodb using the input provided by the user in text fields using nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs to access the mongodb.I am able to query it statically by directly specifying the field values,but i want to query it using the values user will enter it,how should i proceed with it.This is my html file where i am accepting location and time value from the user ,and the get method is called in form action to the specified url:http://localhost:3000/movies,where I have added the find() query to retrieve all the records from the collection such as:

```
     var query={'location':"//the location which user will enter in textbox"};
     db.collection("movie").find(query);
```

My form:

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:3000/movies">
         First Name: <input type = "text" name = "location">  <br>
         Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "timing">
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Help me how can I acheive this?
Thanks!

Comment: What server are you using?  You don't specify anything but the front end and the database.

Comment: You are missing crucial parts. A Fullstack application usually is based on a Front-End (the form in HTML you posted), a Back-End which sanitizes and checks what the user had inputted in the form, and the database to persist the data. You are omitting the Back-End details here.

Comment: @lilezek mongodb database is used ,and I am using nodejs for the communication between the two !

Comment: NodeJS is not a communication tool. You should go deep into the details.

Comment: @Paul Server as in?I did'nt get ?

Comment: If you're using NodeJS as your application server, then that's what I was asking about.  But is it Sails?  ExpressJS? Hapi?  How about showing us something about how you've configured things so we know what to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and try and answer your question despite the limited info.

Basically, your nodejs app has to receive the form data and then put it in the query.

If you're using Express, you'd install body-parser and go from there:

```
// in your app setup code
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// ... any other requires you have

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
// ... any other app.use statements you have

app.post('/movies', (req, res) => {
   var query = { location: req.body.location });
   // the remainder of your code for handling the query and sending a response
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You May try for this:

```
db.yourCollection.findOne({ location: 'the location which user will enter in textbox'}, function (err, info) {
   console.log(info)
});
```

Comment: This isn't a solution for the OP's problems.

Comment: get your data in 
request.body.param,
How can you vote down to it,
it is upto the mark which you asked?

Comment: What request. What body. What param? My god.

Comment: when you hit the server side code then send all the data to that, and the retrieve it on server side and write the query in mongo

Comment: Do you see that your comment doesn't solve the OP's problem? It is a vague description of how web application works.

Comment: @KunvarSingh My problem is how to get that value of the textbox and pass it into the mongodb query command ?

Comment: Ok,
Then use the nodejs architecture and write the API code and from here we will send the data to that api.
and we will write down.
For more info you can contact me on +91 8755732315(whatsapp)